# -ise or -ize in IELTS writing

Tags: british-english

There are many places suggest not to mix British and American spelling in IELTS test, such as the articles on [IELTS-Blog](http://www.ielts-blog.com/ielts-preparation-tips/writing-tips/spelling-in-ielts-british-or-american/) and nativespeakeronline (No link here. I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links).
When I search on forums, the most common idea is people in North America prefer -ize and people in other places prefer -ise. However, an article on [learnenglish.de](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/isevsize.html) says:

> the Oxford University Press insists that words such as computerize, capitalize, capsize, organize, organization, privatize, publicize, realize should take the -ize ending

And for some words in this list like "organization", people on forums say most British still prefer "organisation".
In this case, if I stick to using British spelling on IELTS test, should I use -ise or -ize for the words in this list?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling, http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/ize-or-ise/, and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/ize-ise-or-yse.

Comment: Also [this](http://www.ielts.org/test_takers_information/what_is_ielts/why_choose_ielts.aspx) from IELTS: "IELTS recognises both British and American English in terms of spelling, grammar and choice of words. It also incorporates a mix of native speaker accents from Australia, Canada, New Zealand, the UK and US in the Listening component."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an American and use American spellings for everything. This answer is based on comments, including a [British English speaker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61147/ise-or-ize-in-ielts-writing#comment117379_61147), and internet research.

Most British speakers and publications use -ise endings. However, as you have pointed out, [Oxford Spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling) uses -ize.

This has led to some British English publications and speakers using -ize, while most ignore the guideline and continue to use -ise. Tellingly, the London paper *The Times* switched from using -ize to -ise in 1992.

Therefore, if you're using British spellings for everything else, you should probably use -ise, but shouldn't be penalized for using -ize.

Answer (score 1):

IELTS accepts both spellings: American and British.

So, if you put capital**ize** **(American English)** instead of capital**ise** **(British English)**, it will not be considered a mistake as long as you are consistent. What I mean is that you shouldn't mix them and write: CAPITALIZE (American English) but FAVOUR (British English) in your writing section. Just stick to the spelling you are most comfortable with!

I find https://www.facebook.com/tuto.ielts on Facebook a very helpful resource for IELTS takers. So, check it out as it is created by former Cambridge ESOL Examiners.

Disclosure: I, myself, make regular contributions to that page, which link I provided, so I would be happy to see you there.

Best of luck to you at the exam!

Comment: I notice that you are promoting that Facebook URL in your answers. You should read over [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/273494) You *must* disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers.

Comment: The point in the question is that Oxford dictionaries recommend Capitalize, but many other British English dictionaries use Captialise. So it is not the case that -ize is only American.